# Removing the last trailing underscore from a string

Tags: r, string, gsub

I am trying to remove the last trailing underscore(_) from a string using R.

For example,

```
  Col1
  TX_
  AZ_TX
  CA_LX
  CHI_
  KS_
```

The above strings should look like

```
  Col1
  TX
  AZ_TX
  CA_LX
  CHI
  KS
```

Only the trailing _ be gone. I tried `sub("_", "", my_dataframe$my_column)` but this removes all the _ from the string. I am just looking for a function that removes the last trailing _ and not all. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `sub` (or `gsub`) with the regular expression `"_$"` to find the `_` at the end of the input, then replace with `""`:

```
s <- c('Col1', 'TX_', 'AZ_TX', 'CA_LX', 'CHI_', 'KS_')
sub("_$","",s)
##[1] "Col1"  "TX"    "AZ_TX" "CA_LX" "CHI"   "KS"
```